# C++ : Assignment and checking for NULL on new/delete

Tags: c++

Is the assignment and check for null explicitly required in the below snippet to achieve the same result. Also, is there anything wrong or can be improved here.

```
class Sample
{

private:
    char *bits;

public:

    Sample() 
    {
       bits = NULL; //should this be explicit?
    }


    ~Sample() 
    {
        if (bits != NULL) 
        {
           delete [] bits; //should this be explicit?
        }
        bits = NULL; //should this be explicit?
    }

};
```

Comment: Don't forget the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) when writing classes like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case, where you do this in the constructor:

```
Sample()
{
    bits = NULL;
}
```

Whether or not you need this assignment depends on your code - if `bits` may not have any memory allocated to it at all, then the `NULL` assignment should be there because of the `delete` in the destructor. And really as a safety issue, you would probably want the `NULL` unless you document some contract the user has to obey, but here since you are initializing the pointer to `NULL`, I will assume that means `bits` could realistically be `NULL` or actually have `new`-allocated memory at some point.

If you did not initialize the pointer, and it is never subsequently made 'valid' by being assigned something, and the object is destroyed, then bad stuff happens.

Also, as a habit, [prefer to use initialization lists](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) when possible in constructors:

```
Sample() 
    : bits(NULL)
{

}
```

For the destructor, you do not need to check if a pointer is not `NULL` before deleting it. `delete` on a `NULL` pointer is completely safe. You also don't need to reassign the `bits` pointer back to `NULL`, the object is going away.

```
~Sample()
{
    delete [] bits;
}
```

Of course, if you `delete` an invalid pointer, then bad stuff will happen regardless.

Comment: ok. Aside, w.r.t the above code, are `delete [] bits;` and `delete bits;` equivalent?

Comment: @iJeeves Use `delete bits` for a scalar, and `delete [] bits` for an array. What you have above is correct.

Comment: @iJeeves - sorry, edited my code because your original uses array `delete`, and not scalar. They are not the same thing and using the wrong form is undefined behavior.

Comment: they are not equivalent. delete [] bits means delete an array of char, while delete bits means delete a single char.

Comment: general rule of thumb: if you use [] in new, use [] in delete

Comment: @birryree @Viren Thanks for the initialization list info. I didn't know about it. I think in this particular example there is no performance difference as per the reference. But it'll come of use and it seems to be a good practice to use it. Thanks again!

Comment: more general rule of thumb: if you use [] in new, you're doing it wrong. Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Sample
{

private:
    char *bits;

public:

    Sample() : bits(NULL) //always use member initialization list to init members
    {      
    }


    ~Sample() 
    {   
           delete [] bits; 
    }

};
```